# Counting a specific row in table

Tags: php, mysql, count

Hi i'm trying to count tables where a specific row is more than 0.
if table(requests) have a row(rq_stamp) that is more than 0 it should be counted / selected.

This is what i got so far but i always get 1. ($num_rows is always 1).

```
    $rq_notice = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE rq_poster = '$rq_notice_user' HAVING COUNT(rq_stamp) > 0 ") or die(mysql_error());   
if(mysql_num_rows($rq_notice) > 0 )
{
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rq_notice);
    echo $num_rows;
}
```

Thanks for any help that can be provided, i'm sorry if the question has been answered before but i could not find it when i searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do misunderstand what count does ;)

What you're writing here is a query. In other words, you're sending someone searching for data. What you will get is just what you defined in the SELECT part.

Count is a function that you can use if you group by a specific column. You can here f.e. set a query on a table where you store photos and their uploaders. Using *count* you can now get a number of uploaded photos per uploader. More examples: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

I think you want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM requests WHERE rq_poster = '$rq_notice_user' AND rq_stamp > 0
```

Just get all requests where the poster is X and the timestamp is > 0. And using PHP you can now check how much rows got collected and you can get the rows by using mysql_query. http://php.net/mysql_query

**But please** use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql. I'm here just talking about the functions you use in PHP. The PHP-extension mysql is deprecated since PHP 5.5 and you shouldn't use something, you now know of, will be removed. If you ask, why it is deprecated: https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated

Comment: THX for the help and the heads up about mysqli PDO.
Can you give an example of how to write this in PDO? i would be very thanks full

Comment: Take a look at these tutorials: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php and http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers Please write me a private mail about if you have more questions after reading those because that's no longer related to this question.

Comment: thank you, those where good guides, especially the second one ;).

Answer (score 0):

By using `COUNT()` you are introducting an aggregation into your query which doesn't seem to be necessary. If you are just trying to determine if the value of `rq_stamp` is greater than 0 just do:

```
SELECT * FROM requests WHERE rq_poster = '$rq_notice_user' AND rq_stamp > 0
```